# Renaming Cells In Excel

Tags: excel, rename

I don't know if this is possible, but I have been advised to post here and the most likely place for an answer.

I have four columns in excel as follows

```
A: all product id's
B: reference No.
C: selected product id's
D: product codes.
```

What I would like excel to do is search column A for the id's in column C, and if there is a match, rename it to the corresponding row in column D from the search in column D. I can't use vlookup easily as the product id's in column A may repeat upto 8 times.

I hope that makes sense and I will try to answer all questions that I can. I know nothing about excel, beyond on the basics so if anyone could shed some light on this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Insert a new column before `A`. So now all your columns have shifted up one, i.e. your `A` is now `B` etc.

Now in cell `A1` (the newly inserted `A1`, not your original A1 which is now `B1`)

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, $D$1:$E$1000, 2, 0)
```

where `1000` is whatever your last row is. And drag the formula down.

You haven't specified what happens if an ID is in col `A` but not in col `C`. If you want it to just stay what it was in Col `A` then use this formula instead:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1, $D$1:$E$1000, 2, 0)), B1, VLOOKUP(B1, $D$1:$E$1000, 2, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, it works for the first column, but the others just come up with #N/A in them. Any idea's.

Comment: I have worked out why but don't know how to solve it. When I copy it down it is changing the D1:E1000, to D2:E1001, and missing out on looking in the cells above it. I need the D1:E1000 to stay as it is without the numbers changing when its copied down.

Comment: Mark the range that should remain constant like this: `$D$1:$E$1000`. Now it won't change while copied elsewhere.

Comment: Dan,I managed to sort it by changing the D1 to just D, and then after dragging it down, using find and replace to change D to D1. Thanks for your help -it is a real lifesaver.

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark it as solved if it is correct. Also in this case `$D$1:$E$1000` might be less appropriate than just referencing the enitre column but in general it will not be. If you plan on using Excel even for the simplest of task you need to understand the difference between relative cell references and absolute references. It is a fundamental principal in designing excel formulae. Go through this tutorial: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p5.html I urge to read this, it is essential basic stuff!

Comment: Thanks Dan, Appreciated. Stupid question, how do I mark it as solved? I just added [Solved] into the title. Is this ok?

Comment: Underneath the number with the arrows in the top of the corner (which you can also use to vote an answer up if it helped you or down if it is not an answer or destructive or very wrong) there should be a white tick mark. If you click it it goes green and shows people that the answer is accepted and the question is solved. Don't add [Solved] to the title.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub test()

LastRowA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRowA
    For j = 1 To LastRowC
        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("C" & j).Value Then
            Range("D" & i).Value = Range("C" & j).Address(False, False)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This macro is very unnecessary. If this does give the correct answer (very different from my interpretation of the question), then you can just put this formula in Col D: =MATCH(A1, $C$1:$C$1000, 0) or ="C"&MATCH(A2, $C$1:$C$8, 0) if you want the letter "C" as well.

Comment: @Dan, have you tested? It will check the value in A1, match it to the value in C and in D1 you'll have the position of the value in C.

Comment: I did test, yes. Both gave me the same results. Do you get different results? My formula does exactly what you have described, match returns the position in the array which provided your array starts in row 1 is the same as row number. But I see that I put an A2 instead of an A1 in the second formula though, my bad.

Comment: Of course I get correct results, you doubt my code? ;) Aaah, no problem, mine uses a macro instead of a formula, the only difference.

Comment: I'm not doubting your code, merely saying that the formula solution produces an identical result and expressing my surprise that you asked if I have tested mine without testing it yourself. A solution using worksheet formulae only is preferable to a macro solution for many reasons such as making the worksheet more expressive (easier to follow), being able to undo, responding to worksheet changes on the fly whereas the macro must be rerun after any changes. I was just pointing out that a macro solution shouldn't be considered when a perfectly viable formula solution is available.

Comment: @Dan, I know you didn't mean anything by it and you were just stating a formula is better (which imo is true). But your comment  `If this does give the correct answer (very different from my interpretation of the question)` lead me to believe you never even checked my code, that's all. :) So we both agree our solutions work, yet yours is more suitable seen as though it uses a formula. ;)

Comment: No by that I mean that it is completely different from the solution I had already posted. By correct I mean it depends what the OP meant as the question was very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

So your data is something like this? I don't understand what your expected result is?

```
A  B    C  D    expected result
1  101  1  201  ?
1  102  4  204
2  103
3  104
3  105
4  106
```

Comment: You would also have figures in column E. Then if B matched a figure in D, column A would then show the figure in column E from the same row as column D match.